# Event subscription by ARM template for topic with EndpointType as AzureFunction

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-eventgrid

I am trying to create an event grid topic subscription with **"endpointType": "AzureFunction"**. It is giving following error: -

> "error": {
>       "code": "InvalidRequest",
>       "message": "Invalid event subscription request: Supplied URL is invalid. It cannot be null or empty and should be a proper HTTPS URL
>   like https://www.example.com."   }

My ARM template is given below: -

```
{
      "name": "[concat(variables('eventGridTopicName'), '/Microsoft.EventGrid/', variables('myFuncName'))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/providers/eventSubscriptions",
      "apiVersion": "2019-01-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "topic": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'),'/resourcegroups/', parameters('resourceGroupName'), '/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/', variables('eventGridTopicName'))]",
        "destination": {
          "endpointType": "AzureFunction",
          "properties": {
            "resourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/', variables('funcAppName'), variables('myFuncName'))]",
            "maxEventsPerBatch": 1,
            "preferredBatchSizeInKilobytes": 64
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "advancedFilters": [
            {
              "operatorType": "StringIn",
              "key": "eventType",
              "values": [
                "xyzEvent"
              ]
            },
            {
              "operatorType": "StringIn",
              "key": "subject",
              "values": [
                "xyzEventReceived"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "labels": [],
        "eventDeliverySchema": "EventGridSchema"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('eventGridTopicName')]"
      ]
    }
```

Earlier, I was using EndpointType as a webhook since new event handlers like Azure Function, storage Queues, etc. were not available (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-handlers). I used the generated arm template from Azure portal as shown below: -

[image]

Has anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jakob's suggestion for changing api version worked for me with change in resourceId. Here is my modified working template: -

```
{
      "name": "[concat(variables('eventGridTopicName'), '/Microsoft.EventGrid/', variables('myFuncName'))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/providers/eventSubscriptions",
      "apiVersion": "2020-01-01-preview",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "topic": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'),'/resourcegroups/', parameters('resourceGroupName'), '/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/', variables('eventGridTopicName'))]",
        "destination": {
          "endpointType": "AzureFunction",
          "properties": {
            "resourceId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'),'/resourcegroups/', parameters('resourceGroupName'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('funcAppName'), '/functions/' , variables('myFuncName'))]",
            "maxEventsPerBatch": 1,
            "preferredBatchSizeInKilobytes": 64
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "advancedFilters": [
            {
              "operatorType": "StringIn",
              "key": "eventType",
              "values": [
                "xyzEvent"
              ]
            },
            {
              "operatorType": "StringIn",
              "key": "subject",
              "values": [
                "xyzEventReceived"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "labels": [],
        "eventDeliverySchema": "EventGridSchema"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('eventGridTopicName')]"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes ! found this when I had same issue! ..

Update! found an example that uses another API version and it seems to work beter, now my issue is that there is no code on it when deploying first time, so I need to break the template into two and deploy content in btween (or deploy content via template ofc).

"apiVersion": "2020-01-01-preview",

https://blog.brooksjc.com/2019/07/19/arm-template-for-event-grid-integration-with-a-new-azure-function/

Update 2, after adding the content and rerunning the template, it work fine!

here is my full code for my storage trigger

```
{
            "name": "[concat(variables('storageAccountName'), '/Microsoft.EventGrid/coreCostManagementExport')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/providers/eventSubscriptions",
            "apiVersion": "2020-01-01-preview",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts',variables('storageAccountName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites',parameters('functionAppName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "topic": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts',variables('storageAccountName'))]",
                "destination": {
                    "endpointType": "AzureFunction",
                    "properties": {
                        "resourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/', parameters('functionAppName'), 'QueueUsageOnExport')]",
                        "maxEventsPerBatch": 1,
                        "preferredBatchSizeInKilobytes": 64
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "subjectBeginsWith": "/blobServices/default/containers/usage",
                    "subjectEndsWith": ".csv",
                    "includedEventTypes": [
                        "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated"
                    ],
                    "advancedFilters": [
                    ]
                },
                "labels": [
                ],
                "eventDeliverySchema": "EventGridSchema"
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is confirmed by the [API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.eventgrid/2019-06-01/eventsubscriptions) "For WebHook, the URL that represents the endpoint of the destination of an event subscription."

Comment: sorry I removed my old reply as I found a new one, and I havent seen you had replied!.. but webhook should work but the newer version is better and simpler! :) must be a bug that it doesnt work in the current apis , only the new preview api. Added my working code to my orgiginal reply

Answer (score 1):

In my scenario, I was trying to add a function app Subscription to an event grid topic using "AzureFunctionEventSubscriptionDestination" as the destination. My issue was I missed adding the **/functions/{targetFunctionName}** to the resource id.

"resourceId": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{functionAppName}/functions/{targetFunctionName}"